# Understanding the intuition behind this Markov chain model

Tags: markov-chains, intuition

An airline reservation system has two computers only one of which is in operation at any given time. A computer may break down on any given day with probability $p$. There is a single repair facility which takes $2$ days to restore a computer to normal. Form a markov chain by taking as states the pairs $(x, y)$ where $x$ is the number of machines in operating condition at the end of a day and **$y$ is $1$ if a day's labor has been expended on a machine not yet repaired and $0$ otherwise.**

$$
\begin{array}{c c} 
& \begin{array}{c c } (2,0) & (1,0) & (1,1) & (0,1) \\ \end{array} \\
\begin{array}{c c}(2,0)\\(1,0)\\(1,1)\\(0,1) \end{array} &
\left[
\begin{array}{c c}
q & p & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & q & p \\
q & p & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{array}
$$

I don't understand what $y$ represents in the phrase, "If a day's labor has been expended on a machine not yet repaired".  To me a machine not yet repaired is a broken machine and if the machine is broken then how can you expend a day of labor on it?

Can someone explain the intuition behind this more clearly?  For instance, what does $(1,0) \rightarrow (1,1)$ mean in terms of the real physical thing this is modeling?

Comment: $(1,0)$ means one machine is in operating condition and the other has just broken down.  A day later, if the operating machine is still working (so with probability $q$) then you have one machine in operating condition and the other halfway through its two-day repair shown by $(1,1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A machine can be broken, but the repair facility can fix it.  However, it takes 2 days to fix. We need $y$ to keep track of the machines that have broken down and are in the process of being repaired, having been worked on for one day; one more day's repair will get it back in working order.
Thus if the state is $(1,0)$, we have one working machine and one broken machine that the repair facility has not yet worked on.  It will start now, so that the next day's state will have $y=1$.  With probability $q$, the one working machine stays in working order so the next day's state is $(1,1)$.  But with probability $p$, the working machine breaks down so the next day's state is $(0,1)$.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I misunderstood that as the airline using the computer.